# WMI Type Mismatch when assigning CIM_DATETIME

Tags: c#, wmi

I think the problem I'm having is a type mismatch, between CIM_DATETIME and DateTime.

Below is a function within a generic server class. By the time this function is called I've already created a ManagementScope object and verified the connection by testing a WMI query.

```
public void Sync() 
{
    ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
    ManagementObject classInstance = new ManagementObject(this.Scope, path, null);
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("SetDateTime");
    inParams["LocalDateTime"] = "20170811101838.000000+000";
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("SetDateTime", inParams, null);
    Console.WriteLine(outParams["ReturnValue"]);
}
```

As soon as I try to assign a value to the "LocalDateTime" property I'm met with a Type Mismatch exception.

If I try to get the type of `inParams["LocalDateTime"]` it results in a Null Reference exception. Which leads me to believe that LocalDateTime is not a valid index, or it is but references a null object.

But, I can see that LocalDateTime is a property of `inParams` by enumerating over its properties.

```
foreach (var prop in inParams.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"IsArray : {inParams.IsArray}");
    Console.WriteLine($"IsLocal : {inParams.IsLocal}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Name    : {inParams.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Origin  : {inParams.Origin}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Type    : {inParams.Type}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Value   : {inParams.Value}");
 }
```

This returns the following,

```
IsArray : False
IsLocal : False
Name    : LocalDateTime
Origin  : __PARAMETERS
Type    : DateTime
Value   :
```

So, my questions are

1. How do I properly reference the `LocalDateTime` parameter of the `SetDateTime` method of the class `Win32_OperatingSystem`?
2. Is it possible to cast to `CimType.DateTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this in the future...

I needed to convert System.DateTime to DMTF datetime using the ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDmtfDateTime method.

`inParams["LocalDateTime"] = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDmtfDateTime(DateTime.Now);`

To go the other way, from DMTF datetime to System.DateTime requires using the ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime method.

`var systemDateTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime("20170811101838.000000+000");`